# UART Issues without USB Power

Tags: pi-3, usb, power-supply, uart

I'm experiencing an issue with UART communication when I attempt to power the RPi over the 5V pin instead of the USB port.

Here's a rudimentary look at my setup:

RPi 3B -> Teensy 4.1

GND -> GND

+5V -> +5V

TX -> RX

RX -> TX

+5V and GND are supplied through a battery, measured around 5.1V

Here's what's happening:
With everything hooked up, I'm attempting to send UART signals from the RPi to the Teensy.

1. When I connect the USB power supply to the RPi, everything works as normal. I successfully send messages to the Teensy with NO missed bytes.
2. As I'm sending these signals periodically, I remove the USB power cord (5V still supplied through pin header) and everything still runs on the RPi (HDMI still showing desktop + working terminal), but the UART starts experiencing missed bytes. My guess is probably ~50% misses. I can still control the RPi desktop, send commands through terminal, etc.

Anything else I can do to debug? Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks for any and all help.

-Josh

(repost https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=364181)